# How to Flow annotate a function that returns different types depending on parameters

Tags: javascript, flowtype

See [this example](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzAZwC4CcCWBjVYTABQhUArgHa6ZzlhSbkAmA8ugEoCmqp65AwnAqoAFAG9sg8qgC+ALjDjJqAPzyARnDgwOAQ3LSwAXgXSAlPICC6dDoCeAHmZqAVh1wA+MAB8w5UgFs1DnQFQjBwsEwoMGEJIVNQiKSwdC4eWgBGMIiDDhhkDkTk8NTuXjAAbQBdAG5s8OlCRsJqgDoJSh0ReiZWTjL+JWFTUxIGFnY03gEhMTipeQxSDjMwAGowACYwYGAwAHUAC1swRjgOZDBUQ8xL4PQ4dGUgA) (code repeated below).

I have a function that returns different types depending on the parameters it's called with. How do I get Flow to infer the response type based on the parameter?

```js
/* @flow strict */

function findOrReturnCount({count}: {count?: boolean} = {}): Array<Object> | number {
    if (count) {
        return 1
    } else {
        return [];
    }
}

[].concat(findOrReturnCount())
findOrReturnCount({count: true}) + 2 // Why does this error?
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out. The answer is to use the `declare` keyword to create different function parameters.

[Solution here](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzAZwC4CcCWBjVYTABQhAJgKbYwCG6ZYUArgHa6ZxP2ZMkDyTZACgCUALjABBdOioBPADw8ARgCsKqAHykK1WvWat2nbn0EBvMNjjNUYqFRjI6AX1ESpshSrWbylGnUYWVDYOKC5efgFzS2sxDAZnVyYGAFtFMnRiQINQ8JMomKZUJzFTQtQAfjFFODgYMiomJzAAXjBTFzFJaXklVVx1MAAfMGS0jPbCMGmwTCgwAXKhSZnVsFpUBnQOAEYpmeayBzpTfbX1sk3tsABtAF0AbjOwJ0JXwnuAOksWKlQBMLGSJCISEQERMzlOLoBIuMAAajAACZiD80GAqGIxul0K0jBCohYrEVoQkXqC0XhFF13L0vAM8eD8hT2OjsDSep5+hpGXlItFiTZ6PZHOTUay8CQsakcbygYJlsBgMLMA4wKgZAAHOjYAAWFAA1lwAOZAA)

```js
/* @flow strict */

declare function findOne(): Array<Object>
declare function findOne({ count: false }): Array<Object>
declare function findOne({ count: true }): number

function findOne({count}: {count?: boolean} = {}): Array<Object> | number {
    if (count) {
        return 1
    } else {
        return [];
    }
}

[].concat(findOne())
findOne({count: true}) + 2

const a: number = findOne({ count: true })
const b: Array<Object> = findOne()
const c: Array<Object> = findOne({ count: false })

const d: number = findOne() // fails type checking
```